# Bad parsing Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm new to android and java, and I'm sure this is a rookie mistake but I did not realize it can be.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, anio);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mes);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dia);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, hora);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Log.i("ET","anio: "+anio);
    Log.i("ET","mes: "+mes);  
    Log.i("ET","year: "+c.YEAR);
    Log.i("ET","month: "+c.MONTH);  
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis((int) (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L));
    Log.i("ET","Time c"+c.getTime());
    Log.i("ET","Time calendar"+calendar.getTime());
    return (int) (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L);
```

and the log

```
11-15 23:14:19.528: I/ET(13645): anio: 2013

11-15 23:14:19.528: I/ET(13645): mes: 10

11-15 23:14:19.528: I/ET(13645): year: 1

11-15 23:14:19.528: I/ET(13645): month: 2

11-15 23:14:19.528: I/ET(13645): Time cSat Nov 16 11:14:00 UYST 2013

11-15 23:14:19.528: I/ET(13645): Time calendarFri Jan 16 21:36:47 UYT 1970
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: You've not even mentioned a mistake...?

Comment: I want the first date is equal to the second, the calendar c is always in January 1970 would not have to be equal?

Comment: ..What? You aren't doing any `Date` comparison here. Very confused...

Comment: I set starting date, and then convert it to milliseconds and when the recovery is a standart date apparently is not that I want to recover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference values from a `Calendar` object, you should use the `get(int field)` method, where `field` is a constant from the `Calendar` class, such as `Calendar.YEAR`. So, for example, instead of doing

```
Log.i("ET","year: "+c.YEAR);
```

you should do

```
Log.i("ET", "year: " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

I hope this helps; comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks, that will help me in the future but my current problem is that I want to store a date in milliseconds and then back.
And I can not get it, only recovers Fri Jan 16 21:36:47 UYT 1970

Comment: That's because you're dividing by 1000 in this line: `calendar.setTimeInMillis((int) (c.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L));` When you divide by 1000, you change the value of the milliseconds. That's common sense.

Comment: is not this :( probably at some point I'm doing wrong parsing'll find other ways

Comment: No, this is definitely it. What are you trying to accomplish by dividing by 1000?

Comment: I solved it, not ask me how because I have no idea, thanks for the help. I would put upvote the answer but I have only 11 points and not let me: s

Comment: You can always accept it. Also, you should always understand what fixed your problem. What exactly did you change?